# Django cursor initialization

Tags: python, mysql, django

What would be the difference in using the following two cursors -- that is, how does django 'initialize' its cursor and connection?

(1) Django default

```
from django.db import connection
conn = connection
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

(2) Custom initialization

```
import MySQLdb
self.conn = MySQLdb.connect (
                         host = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'],
                         port = 3306,
                         user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'],
                         passwd = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'],
                         db = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])

self.conn.set_character_set('utf8')
self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
self.cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
self.cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
self.cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

Comment: Some defaults, a wrapper to map db-specific exceptions to common exception types, possibly a debug wrapper... I could go on. What differences are you looking for?

Comment: @knbk I'm looking to see if I need to instantiate my own cursor, or if django's will be sufficient.

Comment: I recommend Django's cursor. The only major difference is that you should catch the exception types from `django.db`, not from the backend you're using. All other differences are configurable. It also reuses the active connection.